# How to load external HTML file into Javascript document object

Tags: javascript, dom

I am looking for the javascript method analogous to PHP's DOMDocument->loadHTMLFILE(), so that I can parse an external html file's contents and extract images. Right now i'm doing it via ajax, which is too slow.

Here is the PHP i use to scrape images, it works. I simply want to do the same thing but browser side so that its faster.

```
if(isset($_POST['link']) && $_POST['link'] !== ""){
    //extract relevant article info from link
    $sourceArray = array();
    $sizeArray = array();
    $link = $_POST['link'];
    //generate new DOMdoc
    $article = new DOMDocument;
    $article ->loadHTMLFile($link);
    //get the largest image
    $images = $article->getElementsByTagName("img");
    foreach($images as $image){
        $source = $image->getAttribute("src");
        if(strpos($source, "http://") !== false){
            $sizeProfile = getimagesize($source);
            $imgArea = $sizeProfile[0] * $sizeProfile[1];
            if($imgArea > 100){
                array_push($sizeArray, $imgArea);
                array_push($sourceArray, $source);
            }
        }
    }
    array_multisort($sizeArray, SORT_DESC, $sourceArray);
    $sourceHTML = "";
    $i = 0;
    foreach($sourceArray as $source){
        $id = 'image'.$i;
        $sourceHTML .= '<img id="'.$id.'" class="notSelectedPicture" src="'.$source.'" onclick="toggleSelectedPicture(\''.$id.'\');" alt="alt">';
        $i++;
    }
    echo $sourceHTML;
    exit();
}
```

Comment: ajax is pretty much your only option, if your JavaScript code is running as part of some web code in a browser.

Comment: You may be implementing your AJAX method incorrectly.  If you are finding your current AJAX method too slow, then you should try to write your own, browser specific AJAX method. Look into the XMLHttpRequest (XHR) API.

Comment: i don't see where ajax comes into play for parsing html, but checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument

Comment: @Pointy it would seem that your right, the document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New Document"); method  creates a new dom doc but i still cant load an entire external html doc into it as with the php loadHTMLFILE() method. i am using my own super light ajax method which works quickly for other implementations, its just that the dom parsing (getting all images, sorting by size, checking for full path ref) takes time and having to echo the result back through ajax.responseText just adds to the time. since JS jas document.images(), i wanted to use that instead.

Comment: Have you considered the use of PHP's `glob()` function?

Comment: the glob() function seems useful only for locating files or directories, not for moving their contents into a DOM document object. Also, I would like to us JS not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax solution works for this purpose. As a client-side language JS does not seem to be capable of getting and parsing external html files in the way that PHP is. In order to cut down on loading time, one should focus on the efficiency of the dom parsing code that the ajax posts to.